# What is the name of the mode encountered with :buffers?

Tags: vim

In vim, typing :buffers and a few other commands shows a results page.  This page feels like a crippled normal mode, as h,j,k, and l can navigate, but other commands like ctrl-u and ctrl-d can't.  Visual mode can't be used to select text in this mode, either.

What is the name of this mode?

Comment: I don't know about the "mode," but it's called the "buffer list." http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_buffer_FAQ

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I'm interested in this question since I've seen it in multiple contexts.  The buffer list is just one of them.  I'm starting to get annoyed with the crippled-vim functionality in this mode, so I want to know where to begin searching for ways to get around this or extend it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The common term for this is the "hit-enter prompt". Rereading the relevant bits in the docs, however, we learn that there are in fact *two* very similar prompt modes. What you are dealing with is the **"more prompt"**.

You can find out everything about it at [`:h more-prompt`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/message.html#more-prompt).